# Connection times out using Connect Using a Java-Based (SSH) Client in Amazon EC2

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am newbie to servers. I am trying to connect to Amazon EC2 micro instance using [Connect Using a Java-Based (SSH) Client](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html#connect-from-browser_steps) but I am getting an error `Connection timed out`as shown below in the image.

[image]

Also I am getting timeout message only when I try to SSH via wireless internet connection, in case of a wired connection could SSH into the instance.

I could not zero out where is the error is?

Answer (score 3):

I figured out what the problem is here. You must [allow your specific IP address or IP address range for inbound SSH traffic in the security group you have associated with the instance you're trying to connect to](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#adding-security-group-rule). Create a new inbound TCP rule for SSH with your IP address (or IP address range) and the attendant [CIDR Subnet Mask](http://doc.m0n0.ch/quickstartpc/intro-CIDR.html) and after that you should be able to connect using Java SSH or any SSH client.

Comment: Let me check this, will get back to you on this.

Comment: Thanks, @codingcrow! Please let me know how if it doesn't work. I can think of some other possible solutions.

Comment: The TCP Port 22 (SSH) has inbound source set at 0.0.0.0/0, which means the port is open for all IP addresses. Even then the problem persists.

Comment: That would be correct (0.0.0.0/0) if you were setting a subnet mask, but this is an IP address range specification not a subnet mask.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a local SSH client that you can use to attempt to connect to the instance?  If so, does that work?

Did you remember to ensure that your IP address (or netblock) is allowed to send traffic to TCP port 22 in your security group for the instance that you just deployed?  You can check this by going running the 'ec2-describe-group' command from the EC2 Toolkit, or by using Amazon's Console and heading to EC2 -> Security Groups and viewing the security group assigned to that instance.

Comment: **local SSH client** - I tries `Putty` and it said `Connection time out`. `Security group` applied has this setting **22 tcp 0.0.0.0/0**. I changed my modem to _D-Link HSPADataCard Diagnostics Interface(COM 11)_ and ISP today.